# In the U.S., is more water used for electric generation, and more electricity used for water infrastucture, than anything else?

Tags: united-states, water, power-generation

Today I received an e-mail message regarding an upcoming [Energy Water Nexus Technical Conference](http://campaign.r20.constantcontact.com/render?m=1118817700271&ca=359efcc5-3929-41e8-9b76-6e8a2506df3a) that made this unsupported claim:

> Nationally, the largest category for water consumption is electric power 
>   generation. Similarly, the largest demand for electricity is water extraction and distribution.

Given the amount of farms and lawns in the U.S., I would expect crop irrigation to be the biggest water user. And, given the population and climate in much of the country, I would expect space conditioning (heating/cooling/ventilation) to be the largest user of electricity.

**Is electric generation the largest user of water, and is water infrastructure the largest user of electric energy?**

Comment: It would not surprise me if there is not some equivocation fallacy behind that claim. Using water for cooling in a power plant only **consumes** water if it is using evaporation cooling towers, and the water can be both brackish and salt, depending on where the plant is. This is in contrast to drinking and irrigation water, which must be fresh. So something is iffy here, because far from all water that is used for cooling in power generation is drinkable water.

Comment: This certainly depends on what you consider to be a "category".  In the EPA's data at https://www.epa.gov/energy/electricity-customers, water extraction and distribution don't appear as a category at all.

Comment: There also might be a "net vs gross" issue in play.  For instance, an awful lot of electricity is used to [pump water up to the top of California's Tehachapi Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonston_Pumping_Plant), and an awful lot of electricity is generated as it flows down the other side.

Comment: Depending on how you defined "used", this could be trivially true for the water-consumption side of things.  For example, there are eleven hydroelectric dams on the Columbia River, and the full flow of the river passes through each of them.  If you count each dam as a "use", you get a total of about 2 billion acre-feet, a number about equal to 40% of the total rainfall on the Lower 48.

Comment: As stated, this question does not make a notable claim. A random email message is not notable.

Comment: I've tried to make this more on topic. A random email message is not notable, while claim in an international technical conference is.

Comment: Yup, that USGS report that David quoted confirms it: the claim is flawed because it conflates **uses** with **consumes**, and that is wrong.

Comment: I think I nailed the first claim as "mostly correct" (or at least it used to be "mostly correct"). I'm having difficulties with the second claim, "Similarly, the largest demand for electricity is water extraction and distribution." The largest consumers of the energy that goes into electricity are the 3rd and 4th laws of thermodynamics, by far. Two thirds of the input energy goes out as waste heat (which is where those big cooling towers come into play). The remaining third is rather dispersed.

Comment: @MichaelK - Uh, no. The vast (overwhelming, pick your adjective) majority of the water consumed by production of electricity goes into vapor (poof!), and a significant majority of the input water to the process is fresh, not brackish.

Comment: @MichaelK - The only way the huge amounts of water consumed to generate electricity in Texas (the biggest consumer by far) is if the water vapor that results from that consumption in turn results in increased rain in Kansas, or some other state similarly situated in the interior of the US.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes it is true that the water that is **consumed** has gone "poof", but that is only 3-4 % of all water that is **withdrawn**. Read the chapter on thermoelectric plants, and compare the tables 2A and 12. The image that you use to justify the claim of power-plants being the second largest "consumers" of water, does not show consumption, it shows **withdrawal**. Withdrawal and consumption are not the same for power plants, they differ by a factor of more than 25.

Comment: I take it we should consider the "nation" in "nationally" to be the US?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No, the claim is faulty on both parts

Using the US Geological Survey report on [Estimated use of water in the United States in 2015](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/cir1441), we quickly see that the original claim that thermoelectrical power-plants **consume** the most water is not correct.

Table 2A shows that thermoelectrical power plants do **withdraw** 133,000 Mgal per day, and that is on par with irrigation, and those two together are the top withdrawers. But 96-97 percent of the water that power plants withdraw is discharged back into the environment and is available for use downstream without further treatment. The **consumptive use** is only 4,310 Mgal per day (Table 12).

With a **consumptive** use of only 4,310 Mgal/day, power plants consume much less than Irrigation (Table 7), at 73,200 Mgal/day, which is 17 times as much.

So when the original claim says that:

> Nationally, the largest category for water **consumption** is electric power generation.

...that claim is false.

As for **usage of electricity**, the claim that making water available is the largest consumer of electricity: no, that is not true either.

As [explained by United States Energy Information Agency](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/index.php?page=electricity_use), the Commercial, Industrial and Residential<sub>(**)</sub> sectors share about equal parts of electricity use.

Water supply sorts under the "Commercial" sector:

> The commercial sector includes retail, office, education, institutional, public, and government facilities, and **public services such as water supply, sewage treatment**, telecommunications equipment, and outdoor and public street lighting.

...and the commercial sector is listed as using electricity for the following:

- Refrigeration—14.0%
- Ventilation—11.2%
- Lighting—10.6%
- Space cooling—10.6%
- Office equipment —7.8%
- Computers and related equipment—7.5%
- Space heating—2.6%
- Cooking—1.8%
- Water heating—0.6%
- Other miscellaneous uses combined—33.3%

So water treatment and water transportation do not even have their separate posts, but instead get sorted in under misc. uses, presumably using less electricity than the 0.6% listed — **in the commercial sector only**, not 0.6% of all use — for water **heating**.

Hence that part of the claim is wrong too.

## Edit: "Use" vs "Consume"

The original claim is the following...

> **Energy Water Nexus Technical Conference: Driving Savings in Manufacturing**
>
> Nationally, the largest category for water consumption is electric power
> generation. Similarly, the largest demand for electricity is water extraction and distribution. This strong interdependence drives great opportunity in the Energy-Water Nexus (EWN) to impact both energy and water consumption.

So what is an Energy Water Nexus? Turns out [Wikipedia has a page on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water-energy_nexus)...

> There is no formal definition for the water-energy nexus - the concept refers to the relationship between the water used for energy production, including both electricity and sources of fuel such as oil and natural gas, and the energy consumed to extract, purify, deliver, heat/cool, treat and dispose of water (and wastewater) sometimes referred to as the energy intensity (EI).

Further down the page, we find the following. *Emphasis* is original, **bold**  is my addition.

> Water can either be *used* or *consumed*, and can be categorised as fresh, ground, surface, blue, grey or green among others. Water is considered **used** if it does not reduce the supply of water to downstream users, i.e. water that is taken and returned to the same source (instream use), such as in thermoelectric plants that **use** water for cooling and are by far the largest users of water. While used water is returned to the system for downstream uses, it has usually been degraded in some way, mainly due to thermal or chemical pollution, and the natural flow has been altered which does not factor into an assessment if only the quantity of water is considered. Water is **consumed** when it is removed completely from the system, such as by evaporation or consumption by crops or humans. When assessing water use all these factors must be considered as well as spatiotemporal considerations making precise determination of water use very difficult.

So, in the context of talking about Energy Water Nexus / water-energy nexus, there is indeed a vital difference between claiming water has been "used" or if it has been "consumed".

The only way the claim about thermoelectric plants and water can be true is if whoever wrote that flyer made a mistake, and erroneously wrote "consumption" when they actually meant "usage". I personally find that to be either unlikely, or really embarrassing on part of someone that supposedly calls to a conference on the subject and thus should know the difference.

And no matter that, it still does not make the second part of the claim — about electricity being used the most for producing and moving water — true.

The following graphic, from the same Wikipedia page...

[image]

*Water / Energy usage and respective dependencies. Image Source: US Department of Energy - Bauer, D., Philbrick, M., and Vallario, B. (2014). "The Water-Energy Nexus: Challenges and Opportunities." U.S. Department of Energy. Public Domain*

...shows that electricity usage to produce water and waste waster treatment is 0.1 and 0.1 [Quads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_(unit)) per year (0.1 Quad = 29 TWh) respectively, while other usage of electricity is substantially more.

The same graphic also shows a very tiny portion of water leaving the "Thermoelectric Cooling" box and going into the "Consumed Water" box. The sums of other connectors means that — according to that graphic — water is **consumed** at a rate of 2,000 Mgal per day out of 196,000 Mgal/day **used** for thermoelectric cooling.

<sub>(**) Anyone else get SimCity vibes from that? :D</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the claim is mostly correct, and hydroelectric dams have little to do with it. Impounded water that falls through a turbine doesn't count as consumption. Thermoelectric consumption of water instead involves turning (somewhat) usable liquid water into one of the following: Water vapor for cooling that goes into the atmosphere, somewhat unusable waste water that is treated as sewage, or quite unusable toxic waste water that needs significantly more treatment than mere sewage. The vast majority of the consumed liquid water is converted to vapor.

The non-parenthetical "mostly" and the parenthetical "somewhat" is because some of the water consumed to generate electricity is saline water. Consumption of water to generate electricity has been dropping for the last few decades (an 18% decline since 2010 alone) while irrigation has been steadily increasing. Apparently irrigation has finally overtaken electricity generation as the number one consumer of fresh water.

Since 1950, the US Geological Survey has produced a report on estimated water use in the US once every five years. The most recent is [Estimated use of water in the United States in 2015](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/cir1441). This document lists hydroelectric generation as the number one consumer, followed closely by irrigation. The following graphic is from that document.

[image: Graphic depicting various consumers of water in the US. Thermoelectric power is #1, using 41% of the supply, followed closely by irrigation at 37%.]

Some of the 41% of the total water supply consumed by thermoelectric electricity production is saline water. Excluding that saline water, thermoelectric consumption came in at number two in 2015, just behind irrigation. This turnaround is very recent. The document sites an 18% reduction in water consumption for generation of electricity. Up until 2015, thermoelectric was the number one consumer in the US of fresh water, well ahead of irrigation consumption.

Comment: I have to down-vote this answer until there is an edit because it fails to distinguish between **use** and **consumption**. In the report quoted, thermoelectric powerplants **use** 95,100 (fresh) + 37,800 (saline) = 133,000 million gallons per day (Table 2A), but they only **consume** 3,760 (fresh) + 547 (saline) = 4,310 million gallons per day (Table 12). The original claim is about **consumption**, i.e. water that gets withdrawn and then not discharged again for further use down the line, but this answer equals **use** with **consumption**, and that makes for a factually faulty answer.

Comment: The image describes "withdrawals", but "withdrawal" is not the same as "consumption". Most of the water (~96-97%) that is withdrawn by thermoelectric power-plants is redeposited and can be used downstream; that portion is **not** consumed. So it appears the original claim is indeed deceiving us by claiming the water is **consumed**.

Comment: @MichaelK - IMNHO, you are reading the document incorrectly. That said, the cited document isn't that great.

Comment: @MichaelK - Moreover, the vast majority of the water consumed by most other processes can, after treatment, be used further downstream. This is why we have sewage treatment plants. This also applies to irrigation. A good chunk of the water used for irrigation goes toward transpiration, a tiny bit goes into the plant, but most of the water consumed for irrigation comes out of the system as water that is somewhat more polluted than the water that went in to irrigate the crops.

Comment: Does thermoelectric cooling water which is withdrawn from a river or the sea and then returned to the same river or sea a few degrees warmer even need further treatment?

Comment: @DavidHammen I outright claim you have not read the document at all, especially not the chapter on thermoelectric power plants, starting at page 42. And you have not compared tables 2A and 12. Table 2A shows that — yes — power plants withdraw the 2nd most of the compared categories, 133,000 Mgal/day. But table 12 shows that the **consumptive use** is only 4,310 Mgal/day. The image you quoted shows **withdrawals**, not **consumptive use**. Compare that to Irrigation (Table 7) where the **consumptive use" is 87,000 Mgal/day. Or table 6, domestric use of 26,000 Mgal/day, that requires treatment.

Comment: And like @Henry just pointed out: discharged once-through cooling water only gets a little warmer, it does not require further treatment to be used again. This while industrial, domestic, agricultural, livestock and mining use of water usually does. So I stand by my comment and my vote: the original claim is not correct, and this answer — that validates the faulty original claim — is also not correct, because it conflates **withdrawal** with **consumption**, and that is wrong to do, which the report clearly shows.

Comment: @MichaelK - It is you who is misreading. That is "other  water". The vast majority of the consumed water goes up in steam. This has to be the case by the laws of thermodynamics. Creating that much energy requires a vast amount of cooling. Without it, the plant would cease to function. The thermodynamic efficiency of power plants is rather low, and even a 100% efficient Carnot cycle machine needs a good amount of cooling.

Comment: Given that the original claim is brief and unreferenced, I doubt the authors gave much though to the choice of words between "usage," "withdrawal," or "consumption." Thus I think this answer backs it up. But what about the electric use aspect?

Comment: @LShaver Suppose I tell you "Lend me $133,000, I will **use** all of that as collateral, $4,310 of that will be invested on your behalf with, and you will get the rest back tomorrow". Now compare this to "Give me $133,000, all of it will be invested, you will get none of it of the back tomorrow". Do you think this is an essential difference? In both cases I have **used** $133,000 dollars, but in one case I have spent (i.e. "consumed") only $4,310, and in the other I have spent $133,000 of your money. I say that is not an insignificant difference. And the claim is "**consume**", not "use".

Comment: @MichaelK oh I agree it's ambiguous at best -- but they're trying to make a point, so I assume the interpretation (wrong or otherwise) that strengthens their point is the one they're going for.

Comment: @LShaver The interpretation that would strengthen their position the most is if thermoelectric power generation cooling **consumed** the most water of all sectors. This is clearly not true. Irrigation "wins" that category by a huge margin, Industry by several hundred percent. So either they messed up and muddled terms that they really ought to be in command of when arranging a Water-Energy nexus conference, or they are being outright deceptive. In either case, **the claim as written** is false. We can only speculate on, and not know, why they got it wrong, if it was accident or intentional.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete without touching the other part of the question: _is water infrastructure the largest user of electric energy?_